# How much space is needed?

Tags: passwords, memory

How much memory is needed if I want to generate a dictionary of all possible combination of length 6 with a-z and 0-9 characters? Is it a good idea to go for cracking password if I know password includes no other character then these and length is 6.
I want to know roughly how much space will be need to write these all possible combinations on disk. I am using ubuntu 12.04 platform. And then I want to use it for brute-force approach to crack the password.

Comment: That would depend on what character set you use.

Comment: Welcome to [security.se]. What problem are you trying to solve, what threat are you trying to mitigate, or what countermeasure are you trying to test? It is unclear from your question what you're wanting to do, and why you think that's a good idea... Perhaps start from there, and we can help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's (26+10)^6  combinations, at 6*16 bits per combination (I'm assuming 16 bit wide ascii because `tchar`)

((37^6)*(6*16)) bits = ((37^6)*(6*16))/(8*1024^3) Gigabytes = 24 gigs.

You can bring it down to 12 gigs if you use 8 bit wide `char` instead of 16 bit wide `tchar` and space is a premium for you.

EDIT: Wait, MEMORY needed? No idea, what software are you using to generate the list? It will take up this much space on your HDD when you save it though.

Also, it actually takes up 1/6th or 2/6ths more space than I originally wrote depending on whether you use 1 or 2 characters to indicate endline (1 on Linux, 2 on Windows, iirc 1 on Mac)